# Codeigniter -> 2 variables inside a controller

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am trying to set up a filter on my website.  Here, I am trying to pass (2) variables (neighborhood and business category).  My problem is when only (1) of them is true and the other is false or one variable does not exist.  I am trying to pull this data from my URL

mydomain.com/controller/function/neighbrohood/biz-category

which translates

mydomain.com/ny/find/$neighborhood/$biz_filter

When I have both variables then there is no problem.

How do I resolve the page with only 1 of the 2 variables there?

Here is my model:

```
    public function search($neighborhood = null, $biz_filter = null) {

    $neighborhood = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $biz_filter = $this->uri->segment(4);

    // SELECT
    $this->db->select('*');

    // MAIN TABLE TO GRAB DATA
    $this->db->from('biz');

    // TABLES TO JOIN
    $this->db->join('city', 'city.city_id = biz.biz_cityID');
    $this->db->join('zip', 'zip.zip_id = biz.biz_zipID', 'zip.zip_cityID = city.city_id');
    $this->db->join('state', 'state.state_id = city.city_stateID');
    $this->db->join('neighborhood', 'biz.biz_neighborhoodID = neighborhood.neighborhood_id');
    $this->db->join('biz_filter', 'biz_filter.bizfilter_bizID = biz.biz_id');
    $this->db->join('biz_category', 'biz_filter.bizfilter_bizcategoryID = biz_category.bizcategory_id');

    // RETURN VARIABLES
    $this->db->where('neighborhood.neighborhood_slug', $neighborhood);      
    $this->db->where('biz_category.bizcategory_slug', $biz_filter);

    // ORDER OF THE RESULTS
    $this->db->order_by('biz_name asc');

    // RUN QUERY
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // IF MORE THAN 0 ROWS ELSE DISPLAY 404 ERROR PAGE
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query;

    } else {
        show_404('page');

    }

}
```

Example. Say I am looking for a Restaurant in Little Italy:

URL = mydomain.com/ny/find/little-italy/restuarants

This part, I can resolve the query correctly and display the data. The issue is when there is no neighborhood or no category, I cannot figure out how to resolve the data.

I am new to codeigniter and a self-taught programmer, trying to figure this out as I go.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it is optional to get the variables from the uri

```
$neighborhood = $this->uri->segment(3);
$biz_filter = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

You already have that from your function parameter.

You can check the condition where your $neighborhood or $biz_filter is available or not then you can use condition in your query.

Something like this

```
if($neighborhood) { // query for neighborhood } elseif($biz_filter) {}
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you for your reply.  would this only work if i wanted to return one or the other?  These are each filters, so the user will have the option to select neighborhood + category or one of the two.  would i nest it with different IF statements to account for each scenario?

Comment: also in place of the missing variable i want that segment to contact "-" instead of being blank.  If you could help suggest a way to structure the missing variable too in the url, i would really be greatful.

Comment: When you generate urls then you can check if the variable is available or not then if the variable is not available you can add a default string. Something like:
mydomain.com/ny/find/little-italy/default  Then You can process the default string from your controller

Comment: i was able to figure out the first part.  now the issue is in the url, if that variable does not exist, I represent it with "-" however, when informing the user what the results they will see, it repeats 3x if one of the variables is missing.  Does that make sense how I am explaining it?

Comment: you can replace with any string but be sure you are process that from controller

Comment: i just came across that error.  so now if the segment = "-" it will display the string, but if there is a neighborhood in the database i get an error "Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string".  I know it has something to do with the foreach output, but if i do that, then i get the 3x repeats for the value when = "-" .  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get the variable values from your controller not your model, you should then pass such values to your controller from your model, its bad coding practice to allow your view interact with the model.

Also, if you want a value of "-" set for the variable. You should set "-" as the return value right from the parameters being passed to the controller.

What you should do is go to your controller and give it the two parameters, set default values for both and also go to your model and make it receive two parameters also, pass the parameters to the model when calling from the controller. Then get back if there are any more errors.